# I am trying to create a user profile for my project by using dual ngIf directives

Tags: angular, angularfire, angular8, angular-ng-if

I am setting up updating/ editing user profile by using two ngif statements however, there seems to be an error as Angular can't read the properities.

I tried removing a single property for *ngIf however it still does not work.

user-dashboard.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <!-- Spread the toolbar item apart.-->
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button mat-button (click)="editing=false" *ngIf="editing">Done</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="editing=true" *ngIf="!editing">Edit Profile</button>

</mat-toolbar>

<!-- Only when there a user.-->
<ng-container *ngIf="user">
  <div [hidden]="editing">view mode</div>
  <div [hidden]="!editing">editing mode</div>
</ng-container>
```

user-dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';

import { AuthService } from '../../core/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { User } from '../user.model';


user-dashboard.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './user-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class UserDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  editing = false;
  user: User;

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.auth.user.subscribe(user => (this.user = user));
  }
}
```

Upon clicking on the button, and **ONLY WHEN A USER DATA EXIST**, edit profile = view mode, view profile = done.

Comment: Posting the complete error message would help.

Comment: Hi, the console didn't output any error messages! At most it's just show

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: However, this doesn't really affect the problem I am facing because the system can't read the user being presented.

Comment: It seems to me you may have to create a condition on the subscription. Perhaps creating a reference `isUserAuth: boolean` and go with that. Can you console.log the user and post here? For both cases, authenticated and not authenticated.

Comment: How do I do that? @iconio

Comment: Hi @iconio I still haven't added authentication yet! Since I am still learning to how to show the user.

Comment: You can use a library called AngualrFire2, it will simplify a bit your code. You can get it here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

You can create the login like:
```
isUserAuth: false;
constructor (private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

loginUser(email: string, pass: string) {
   this.auth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(
      data => {
           if (data.user.uid) {
              this.isUserAuth = true;
           }
      }
   );
}
```
This is a very simplified way that I think will achieve what you need.
Good luck!

Comment: I didn't realized it would break the comment. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By (click) event try to call functions not logic.

Temaplate:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user">
<button mat-button *ngIf="editing" (click)="onEditing()">Done</button>
<button mat-button *ngIf="!editing" (click)="onEditing()">Edit Profile</button>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts:

```
onEditing() {
this.editing = !this.editing
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but what about my users? Because only when there is a user then I want to show the ng-container. If no user exist then I don't want to show the done/ edit profile.

Comment: Hi... I really want to thank you for taking your time to help me solve my issue!

Comment: There is no error message in the console log and still show the same output!

Comment: @speedie So try like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the authentication piece that I mentioned in the comments.

I would recommend you to use AngularFire2, it's an amazing library for Firebase and Angular. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

```
isUserAuth: false;
constructor (private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

loginUser(email: string, pass: string) {
   this.auth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(
      data => {
           if (data.user.uid) {
              this.isUserAuth = true;
           }
      }
   );
}
```